# Checking if a Process is Currently running by name in rust

Tags: rust, process

How would I check if a process such as "example.exe" is currently running using the rust programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [sysinfo crate](https://crates.io/crates/sysinfo), or particularly [processes_by_name](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/latest/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html#method.processes_by_name)

You can get iterator to processes containing the *name* using the function

```
fn processes_by_name<'a>(&'a self, name: &'a str) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Process> + 'a>
```

You can use it like this

```
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};

let s = System::new_all();
for process in s.processes_by_name("htop") {
    //check here if this is your process
}
```

UPDATE: New version (0.23.0) also contains [processes_by_exact_name](https://docs.rs/sysinfo/latest/sysinfo/trait.SystemExt.html#method.processes_by_exact_name)

It returns an iterator to processes with the exact given name
You can use it like this

```
use sysinfo::{ProcessExt, System, SystemExt};

let s = System::new_all();
for process in s.processes_by_exact_name("htop") {
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: no method named `get_process_by_name` found for struct `sysinfo::System` in the current scope

Comment: Is it for windows?

Comment: Yes @Mintybits its available for Android,
iOS,
Linux,
macOS,
Raspberry Pi,
and Windows

Comment: Thanks @FrancisGagné , updated according to new version